# Buttons disappear on React slide-out

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to make custom controls for a video player. Part of the reason is because hovering over the video to bring up controls is not what I want. Instead, I want a "Show Controls" button that you can press to display them. Right now, I have that working and I'm using `react-transition-group` to make a Slide function with React.

However, the problem is that when the controls slide back out, they awkwardly go below the video frame before disappearing. I want it so that as the button dips below the video frame, it disappears gradually until they are all below the frame. I though that changing the z-index of the buttons on exit-active/enter-active might work but it didn't seem to have an effect. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: How about a link to a demo codepen/fiddle?

Comment: Please include a minimum, verifiable, example of your current code

Comment: I had a lot of trouble putting mine on JSfiddle because it relies on a lot of local files.
This is basically what I want, but instead of going off the side I want it to think of the edge of the video frame as the boundary. I know you can't help me directly without code, but theoretically should I be doing this by manipulating z-index? I don't understand how else but that isn't working for me
https://codepen.io/bjornholdt/pen/MpXmmL

Comment: Can anyone explain why this doesn't work at all? If I can get this working I can show what I mean.
https://jsfiddle.net/xtbxk20g/115/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xtbxk20g/116/ @ColeFaraday
This is the best I could get. It only works on the initial slide. When the button is halfway through its transition outside of the green panel, I want that half of the button to not be showing.